# What is the different between two commands in a Batch file, which returned the drive letter.

Tags: batch-file

I have a question about two different commands in a Batch file. 
The following two commands have the same output but i would like to know, if there is an important different, which i have to know before i use it.

```
echo %cd:~0,2%

echo %~d2

Outputs the drive letter :
E:
E:
```

Answer (score 1):

The two commands are actually quite different.

The first command is a [substring](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.MidString) of the `%cd%` variable, which contains the current directory. It takes whatever your current directory is, starts at the first character in the string (hence the `0`) and returns the next two characters from that point on.

The second command is a [parameter extension](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) returns the drive of the file passed in as the second argument to your script.

```
%~f1 Expand %1 to a Fully qualified path name - C:\utils\MyFile.txt

%~d1 Expand %1 to a Drive letter only - C:

%~p1 Expand %1 to a Path only e.g. \utils\ this includes a trailing \ which will be interpreted as an escape character by some commands.

%~n1 Expand %1 to a file Name without file extension C:\utils\MyFile or if only a path is present (with no trailing backslash\) - the last folder in that path.

%~x1 Expand %1 to a file eXtension only - .txt

%~s1 Change the meaning of f, n, s and x to reference the Short 8.3 name (if it exists.) 

%~1   Expand %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")

%~a1 Display the file attributes of %1

%~t1 Display the date/time of %1

%~z1 Display the file size of %1

%~$PATH:1 Search the PATH environment variable and expand %1 to the fully qualified name of the first match found.
```

Comment: @poprock - in your example, you would use 2 instead of 1; I'm just quoting the site I pulled the data from. If your argument isn't the full path of a file, none of these are going to work.